# How to line up armature and mesh after deleting the armature modifier?

Tags: armature

So I accidentally deleted the armature modifier and when I go to make another one, my object warps. When I try un-checking vertex groups, the armature will line up with the object again but I cant use it for animation. So how do I line up the armature and mesh with keeping vertex groups checked?

Before adding armature modifier
[image]

After adding armature modifier
[image]

Comment: Could you upload your blend files here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so I can try to help you?

Comment: Here's a link to it [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4950" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4950/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this follow the below steps:

1. Select your mesh
2. Hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and choose apply Scale
3. Do same step 2 and apply location and rotation
4. Select your armature
5. Switch to Pose mode
6. Hit <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> and choose "Apply Pose as Rest Pose"
7. Select Mesh then select armature and hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
8. Parent with automatic weighting

It will be working fine as shown below:

[image]

Comment: So when I did step 6, there was no option to apply Scale. The only option was Play Recorded Animation.

Comment: @Bionicman30 Sorry, I made a typo mistake in step 6. Answer updated.